# Reading Shiva and Skanda Puranas (Shaivite) leads to condemnation to hell? See the screenshot

Tags: puranas, shaivism

[image]

It's from the 3rd Volume of The History and Culture of the Indian People.

Comment: The concept of sattvika, rajasika and tamasika puranas is a meaningless interpolation and does not deserve much attention.

Comment: Padma Purana: Shaivite Puranas are tamasic and lead to hell, Skandha Purana: Vaishnava Puranas are tamasic, lead to hell... In other places in Padma Purana also: all Puranas are good, in Skanda Purana also: all Puranas are good.. so you can quote anything to prove anything surfacely...

Comment: I have read myself the Brahmavaivarta & Vamana Puranas. They don't contain a single line that glorifies Brahma over Vishnu. So the person who added such lines was surely not Krishnadwaipayana Vedavyasa, because He can't be ignorant about His own compositions.

Comment: The deeper meaning is delusion, not the actual hell.